# I want to subtotal/running total in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have set of data, in xlsx format, an example in (pic1) that I want to subtotal/running total as in (pic2). It would be a great help if I achieve this automatically.

[image: **Original data**]

[image: **How it should be**]

NOTE: the result could be in another table, a separate sheet or in the same cell.

Comment: if you want to put the sum in cell D2.. where will you enter the value 4 then ?

Comment: In general the cell could not contain both the value & formula but yes if you want to use formula cell's value (result) for the calculation then,, you may think for Iteration,, so please [Edit] your post & be clear.

Comment: If you can place your PIC2-datas on a second sheet, you can use the following formula `=SUMME(Sheet1!$B2:Sheet1!B2)` in cell B2 and the fill out the other cells.

Comment: It would be a better idea to have a running total on top of the data so that you only need on formula in one cell.

Comment: @Mario I used your formula but it returns ?NAME# .
Could you help me with this?

Comment: @wbeard52 how to do so?

Comment: it returned NAME# because you worksheet name is not Sheet1 (as per default new excel file), just replace Sheet1 in the formula with your sheet name.

Comment: You might receiving that error message as SUMME is not available in a lot of versions of Excel. I believe that is language based. Try using SUM instead. Of course the data or result would have to be in different cells as cells can not reference themselves in formulas.

Comment: Thanks, @BradR this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell A6, put `=A1` then drag till D6.

In cell A7, put `=A2` the drag till A9.

In B7, put `=sum($B2:B2)` then drag till D9.

Done. I think that's it.

Idea : $ is used to 'lock' the row/column, the array defined in sum() change dynamically as you drag/extend it.

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.